# 「ご確認なさってください」って変？

Tags: word-choice, keigo

普通「ご確認ください」を使っています。

それで、「ご確認なさってください」って何か変だと感じますが、何故か説明して頂けるなら助かります。

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I feel like there's a jarring mix of 丁寧語 and 口頭語 going on in both the body and title of this question.

Comment: It's called 二重敬語, and is not correct. Only one "敬語" can be add to a word.

Comment: @fefe 「なさってください」という表現を例にして回答で説明して頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: ご...なさる and ご...くださる are two ways of forming 敬語, and not be used on one word. Use either one of them is OK, but no together.

Comment: 調べてみれば、「ご養生なさってください」が普通に使われたようです...

Comment: I wonder if なさる＋くださる is the problem here?

Comment: Both of them are 尊敬語... （なさる＝「する」の尊敬語、くださる＝「くれる」の尊敬語）

Comment: @fefe 二重敬語 themselves are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

「ご確認ください」は尊敬語、「確認なさってください」も尊敬語なので「ご確認なさってください」は二重敬語かもしれませんね。しかし、いずれにしても問題ない表現だと思います。変に感じるかどうかは個人差のある問題だと思います。

P.S. 一般に、尊敬語の命令形は（尊敬語ではなく）丁寧語になります。命令形は聞き手へ向けられるものであるところ、聞き手への敬意を表すのは丁寧語だからです…多分。

Answer (score 1):

The root expression is 
（確認する | conjunctive form）＋（くれる｜command form）
= 確認してくれ

This first part 確認して can be interpreted as either 
(1) a single verb phrase "確認して", or 
(2) noun 確認 + verb して

(2) is the historical interpretation but in recent years (1) has become more common.

First we look at case (1).  When applying keigo type expressions such as sonkei and kenjyo to the verb, we must apply them to the final verb.  Applying keigo to both is called "double keigo", and it is wrong - although even NHK announcers are prone to this mistake. The result is "確認してください".  However this is still the "くれ" strong command form phrase, and we would like to apply the "ます" teineigo in it's command form ”ませ”. This gives us the even more keigo meaning sentence 
"確認してくださいませ".

Looking at case (2), 確認 is a noun.  The honorific ご is a form of teineigo which can be placed before the noun as a form of decoration.  It is not a sonkei or kenjyuu expression, so it is not at all required to be present.  The rest follows as in case (1), so we get
"ご確認してくださいませ"
or just 
"確認してくださいませ"

Reference: http://www.excite.co.jp/News/lifestyle/20140306/Okguide_2452.html?_p=2

Disclaimer: I largely translated the reference, changing 参考に to 確認.  The comment about NHK announcers was in the reference　- I deny personal responsibility for any slander.

Comment: Thank you for the translation. I think you'll need to remove the に from【確認にする】; it applies to 参考 but not to 確認

Comment: @sazarando - Ooops.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a idea that it is natural. http://news.mynavi.jp/news/2015/06/11/042/

It seems be called 敬語連結. If two honorific words are connected with て, it is used. For example, おっしゃってください.  http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11120121226

Comment: What about おっしゃい＋なさい then? I was under the impression that that was correct as well... Oh, I think you're missing a 「っ」there by the way.

Comment: It seems to be used as well. For example, ごらんなさい,お上がりなさい. http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/34meirei.html#34.3

Comment: Does ご覧なさい apply to this case? After reading the chiebukuro article you shared, I'm wondering if おっしゃいなさい would still be OK because there is no 接続助詞「て」in between おっしゃい and なさい、and both of them are 尊敬語, so that would be 二重敬語, right?

Comment: 二重敬語 is what two honorific words is used for one word. ごらんなさい is connected with two words of ごらんになる and なさい. so I guess it is accepted without　て.

Comment: Wouldn't that be 「ご覧になりなさい」?

Comment: 「二重敬語 is what...words...is used...」 ⇒ 「二重敬語 is when...words...are used」 (in this case)

Comment: なさい is an imperative form of 尊敬語 なさる but なさい itself is not a 尊敬語 but a 丁寧語.